# Getting Nested JsonObjects & Arrays Using Retrofit Library

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I got tired using this library, this is my first time using it and made a lot of success ways, but i'm a bit confused in getting the following Json :

```
{
  "Guides":
            {
            "English":    {"ArabicSony":"Test1","ArabicNexus":"Test2","ArabicSamsung":"Test3","ArabicHTC":"Test4"}
            ,"Arabic":    {"EnglishSony":"Test1","EnglishNexus":"Test2","EnglishSamsung":"Test3","EnglishHTC":"Test4"}
            }

}
```

Googled and saw a lot of guides and answered, and made my List like this :

```
public class PostItem {

List<PostItemArabic> Arabic;
List<PostItemEnglish> English;

}

class PostItemArabic{

private String ArabicSony;
private String ArabicNexus;
private String ArabicSamsung;
private String ArabicHTC;

public String getArabicSony() {
    return ArabicSony;
}

public void setArabicSony(String arabicSony) {
    ArabicSony = arabicSony;
}

public String getArabicNexus() {
    return ArabicNexus;
}

public void setArabicNexus(String arabicNexus) {
    ArabicNexus = arabicNexus;
}

public String getArabicSamsung() {
    return ArabicSamsung;
}

public void setArabicSamsung(String arabicSamsung) {
    ArabicSamsung = arabicSamsung;
}

public String getArabicHTC() {
    return ArabicHTC;
}

public void setArabicHTC(String arabicHTC) {
    ArabicHTC = arabicHTC;
}

}

class PostItemEnglish{

private String EnglishSony;
private String EnglishNexus;
private String EnglishSamsung;
private String EnglishHTC;

public String getEnglishSony() {
    return EnglishSony;
}

public void setEnglishSony(String englishSony) {
    EnglishSony = englishSony;
}

public String getEnglishNexus() {
    return EnglishNexus;
}

public void setEnglishNexus(String englishNexus) {
    EnglishNexus = englishNexus;
}

public String getEnglishSamsung() {
    return EnglishSamsung;
}

public void setEnglishSamsung(String englishSamsung) {
    EnglishSamsung = englishSamsung;
}

public String getEnglishHTC() {
    return EnglishHTC;
}

public void setEnglishHTC(String englishHTC) {
    EnglishHTC = englishHTC;
}
}
```

My Model :

```
    private class Model {
    private List<PostItem> Guides;

    public List<PostItem> getGuides() {
        return Guides;
    }

    public void setGuides(List<PostItem> roms_center) {
        this.Guides = roms_center;
    }

}
```

And printing the result like this :

```
                List<PostItem> Guides = response.body().getGuides();

            for(int i = 0 ; i < Guides.size() ; i ++ ) {
                for (int b = 0; b < Guides.get(i).English.size() ; b++){
                    Log.LogInfo("English Result Is: " + Guides.get(i).English.get(i).getEnglishHTC());
                    Log.LogInfo("English Result Is: " + Guides.get(i).English.get(i).getEnglishNexus());
                    Log.LogInfo("English Result Is: " + Guides.get(i).English.get(i).getEnglishSamsung());
                    Log.LogInfo("English Result Is: " + Guides.get(i).English.get(i).getEnglishSony());
                }
                for (int b = 0; b < Guides.get(i).Arabic.size() ; b++){
                    Log.LogInfo("Arabic Result Is: " + Guides.get(i).Arabic.get(i).getArabicHTC());
                    Log.LogInfo("Arabic Result Is: " + Guides.get(i).Arabic.get(i).getArabicNexus());
                    Log.LogInfo("Arabic Result Is: " + Guides.get(i).Arabic.get(i).getArabicSamsung());
                    Log.LogInfo("Arabic Result Is: " + Guides.get(i).Arabic.get(i).getArabicSony());
                }
            }
```

My work isn't correct, and getting a lot of errors,

Here's the last error i got :

```
`Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 3 column 18 path $.Guides
```

What's the way to make it correct ? `

Answer (score 0):

Based on your models when you try to get the guides list your telling retrofit to populate an array. Retrofit is then getting the data and finding that it is a single object and not array. So you need to update your model to reflect the data returned. For example:

```
class PostItem {
   List<Language> mLanguages;
} 

class Language{
   String mLanguageTitle; //for example english
   List<String> mData; //for this is your list of data
}
```

Then in your activity instead of getting guides you would get just a post item for example:

```
response.body().getPostItem();
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Please explain more, based on my model, based on yours, mLanguages = English/Arabic, ? ..etc?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use the retrofit Gson library.

You can handle this in two ways:

Option 1: reformat your languages in your json to be an array like Doug says.

```
{

"Guides":
        [
        {"Lang":"English","ArabicSony":"Test1","ArabicNexus":"Test2","ArabicSamsung":"Test3","ArabicHTC":"Test4"}
        ,   {"Lang":"Arabic","EnglishSony":"Test1","EnglishNexus":"Test2","EnglishSamsung":"Test3","EnglishHTC":"Test4"}
        ]

   }
```

Then you will need to redesign your class to reflect this structure.
Like Doug sayd:

```
 class PostItem {
     List<Language> mLanguages;
 }
```

Option 2: Create a custom json desirializer in your class. this will take the Json and break it down into whatever structure you want it to be.

```
public class PostItem implements JsonDeserializer

@Override
public MyDesirializer deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
    JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

    JsonObject jarabic = (JsonObject) json.get("Arabic");
    //whatever manipulations you want to do (fill with your own code)
    PostItem item = new PostItem();
    item.arabic = jarabic;
    ...
    ...

    return item;
}
```